# nodejs res.redirect,but http status code is 304

Tags: node.js, redirect, http-status-code-304

Use session as Interceptor， the code is like this

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var url = req.originalUrl;
        var arr =[];
        arr = req.originalUrl.split('/');
        if (arr[1] != "login" && !req.session.user) {
               return res.redirect(302, "/login");   
        }
        next();
    });
```

Then I receive http status code as 304, the page is not refresh 
[image]

**how can I made status code is 302 and refresh the page?**

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are setting `302` status of the `url` where redirection is happening, not of login page.

With this code, e.g., if you hit the url '/home' (where your authorization conditions are failing), then you are setting the status code `302` of `/home`, not of `/login`.

**Solution**

Set the status of `login` route.

E.g.

```
app.get("/login", function(req, res){
     return res.status(302).send('Welcome to login page');
});
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: the status code is 302 now, but the page is not refresh

Comment: what do you mean by page is not refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

304 status code is if the page is loaded from cache memory instead of redownloading it from server to get 302 just clear cache and do a hard reset